# PHP Session Modified on redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect

I am having a weird issue where for some unknown reason my $_SESSION['last_uri'] variable is being modified on a js redirect.

This is where we define the SESSION variable, currently it displays as '/training_management':

```
echo 'SESSION: ' . $_SESSION['last_uri'];

if ( !(preg_match('/login/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) && !(preg_match('/denied/',       $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) ) {
    $_SESSION['last_uri'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This is where we redirect to a new page:

```
$("#login_button").click(function() {
    var name = $("input[name$=name]").val();
    var pw = encodeURIComponent($("input[name$=password]").val());
    var query = "func=login&name=" + name + "&password=" + pw;
    ajaxRequest(query, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        data = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s)/gm, "");
        if (!data || data == 0) {
            failureMsg(_("Incorrect login data."));
        } else {
            window.location.replace("redirect");
        }
    });
});
```

This then redirects to redirect.php which shows the following as the value '/tpl/css/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png':

```
if ( $_SESSION['last_uri'] ) {
    echo $_SESSION['last_uri'];

    //header("Location: " . $_SESSION['last_uri']);
}
```

Where / How is the SESSSION variable changed?

HERE are my rewrite rules:

```
# No www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# No likey .php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Some more Security
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} proc/self/environ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*(.*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /security [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are you using url rewriting? It looks like you are rewriting a bit too much.

Comment: if you've got mod_rewrite rewriting all of your requests to a PHP script, then hitting a particular page may well trigger a whole bunch of re-writes: one for the actual page, and extras for every external resource on that page (e.g. images, css, js).

Comment: Added rewrite rules to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what happend (see comments):

```
echo 'SESSION: ' . $_SESSION['last_uri']; // display /training_management

if ( !(preg_match('/login/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) && !(preg_match('/denied/',       $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) ) {
    $_SESSION['last_uri'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    echo 'NEW SESSION: ' . $_SESSION['last_uri']; // display /tpl/css/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
}
```

Other possibilities:

- /tpl/css/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png not found redirect to a PHP page that modify the session.
- session_start() is missing.

Comment: redirect.php does not load header.php which includes the definition of $_SESSION['last_uri']

Comment: Yes but you test your variable with echo before the variable is setted so your test can be wrong.

Comment: tail session_log 


last_uri|s:53:"/tpl/css/images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png";
last_uri|s:43:"/tpl/css/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png";
last_uri|s:20:"/training_management";
last_uri|s:20:"/training_management";
last_uri|s:53:"/tpl/css/images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png";
last_uri|s:43:"/tpl/css/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png";
last_uri|s:43:"/tpl/css/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png";username|s:13:"matthewharris";logged_in|i:1;auditor_id|s:4:"3042";access_level|s:1:"6";